# Doubt about my GAM formula, is it the right model to use for my data?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, biostatistics, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I measured a physiological performance of a specie (n=16) at 8 different temperatures, the same animal was used for each temperature and are identified by their "ID".

I want to model the non-linear effect of temperature on this physiological performance, taking into account the sex of the animal (6 females and 10 males), the size of it, and the repeated measurement on each individual.

Below is a quick sample of my data:

```
    ID      Sex    Temperature  size Performance
   <fct>   <fct>        <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 4761517 male           9    55.2     1700
 2 4761330 male          14    54.0     1440
 3 4761239 female        29    68.5     2860
 4 4761324 male           4    65.6      530
 5 4761477 female        24    69.6     4350
 6 4761157 male           2.8  63.7        0
 7 4761336 female         9    66.5     2080
 8 4761477 female         2.8  69.6        0
 9 4761460 male          19    76.0     3630
10 4761324 male           2.8  65.6        0
```

I've decided to run a Generalized Additive Model (GAM) using this formula:

```
ModelPerformance <- gam(Performance ~ Sex + s(size) + s(ID, bs="re") + 
                 s(Temperature, k=7),
                 method= "REML", data=Data)
```

Below is what the `summary.gam` gives me:

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
Performance ~ Sex + s(svl) + s(ID, bs = "re") + s(Temperature, 
    k = 7)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1707.9      115.1  14.836   <2e-16 ***
Sexmale       -161.1      157.3  -1.024    0.308    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                 edf Ref.df      F p-value    
s(size)         3.924  4.323   4.72 0.00154 ** 
s(ID)          5.143 13.000   0.72 0.03376 *  
s(Temperature) 5.285  5.788 111.84 < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.849   Deviance explained = 86.7%
-REML = 964.96  Scale est. = 2.2477e+05  n = 128
```

Below is the plot from the temperature effect
[image]

Am  I using a correct formula to model my data?

Because animals have the same size in each temperature measured (see female ID 4761477) I kind  of feel like I am missing something, but what?

I'm also worried about the fact that I incorporated temperature where performance is equal to 0 (min 2.8 and max 38.8), this to root my model at zero for the known physiological thermal limits of the animals.

In the plot below I did not use the 0 performance values and my predicted values do root to 0 for low temperature at -5°C which is way below their biological lower thermal limits and for high temperature at 180°C which is biologically impossible...
[image]

Comment: If the 0 performance values are values that you imposed on the data set rather than actually measured, as I infer from the question, I'd be quite worried about your model. That's effectively making all sorts of assumptions about what's going on at temperature extremes that you didn't directly observe. Extrapolation beyond observation limits can be bad enough without forcing your model (more or less, given the GAM smoothing) to go through points without actual data. What happens if you don't impose those 0 values and just stick with the temperatures at which you made measurements?

Comment: The 0 performance values comes from known critical thermal limits of the animal that I did measure but were not actually measured for the performance specifically. I firstly tried to not impose those 0 performances values. It results in predicted values crossing 0 at temperature close to -5°C which is lower than their critical lower limit of activity but more importantly the predictions do not root to 0 (well it does at 180°C...) for high temperature, which is biologically impossible.  (I've added both curve to my question)

Comment: Limit your analysis to temperatures over which you measured performance and do not try to extrapolate to temperatures outside that range. Setting performance to 0 at the high temperature imposes a particular shape on the curve beyond 29 degrees for which you have no experimental justification. Perhaps the plateau in performance is maintained out to 35 degrees or more and just falls off rapidly thereafter. Don't make up performance data beyond your observed limits and don't try to make predictions beyond those limits.

Comment: I do agree with your statements, thanks for taking the time to give me these advices.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, the main problem with the original model was its assuming values of 0 for performance at extreme temperature limits even though there were no performance measurements at those limits. With the smoothing inherent in the generalized additive model (GAM), that imposed a shape on the fitted curve that wasn't supported by data outside the range of observations. In particular that affected the temperature relationship beyond the highest observed value of 29 degrees, but there are hints of associated effects down to values of 19 degrees when you compare against the model that was restricted to observed temperature values.

The best way to handle this type of data is to fit the data you have and recognize that you shouldn't extrapolate to predictor values beyond that. You could, for example, discuss how you know that performance will drop to 0 at high temperatures but that you don't know at what point or how quickly above 29 degrees.

Beyond that I don't see any problems with the modeling, although I don't have experience including random effects in `gam()`. Yes, the size for each individual was the same under all conditions but that sort of thing is quite common in regression modeling. You seem to have incorporated size pretty well into the model.

You haven't allowed for interactions among the predictors, while smoothed modeling of interactions is a strength of GAM approaches. If that's a deliberate choice based on your understanding of the subject matter that's OK.